# Loading async inside or outside react component

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

It's a design question instead of implementation question.

I have a few React panels following the same pattern:

1. Loading data asynchronously;
2. Showing a spinner during loading;
3. When data loading fails, showing the error message;
4. Showing actual controls when data is loaded;

These panels have a common sub-component which is displayed exactly the same everywhere. This sub-component also depends on data loaded asynchronously at panel level.

Now I have 3 approaches to implement

1. Passing data loaded at panel level to this sub-component, either by props passing or context. Cons. Have to deduplicate such logic in every panels.
2. Moving async data loading into the sub-component so that there is no duplicated code in each panel. Cons. Have to deal with loading state and potential failure within sub-component; It's also strange to show loading state after spinner completes.
3. Pre-loading and storing the data the sub-component depends on globally, so that the sub-component depends on synchronous data. It works as the specific data doesn't  change frequently. Cons. It pollutes global namespace and have to deal with loading/failure status separately.

Do you have any best practice of designing such components? Currently I choose option 1 to make UI consistent and easy to deal with loading/failure status.

Comment: In your Con remark for approach 1, what do you mean by "have to deduplicate such logic  in every panel". Which logic exactly needs duplication there?

Comment: Duplicated code means 1. code fetching async data; 2. code passing data from panel level to the sub-component.